# What does `chmod u+s directory` do?

Tags: linux, chmod

`chmod g+s directory` makes new files inherit the group of the directory. I thought that `chmod u+s directory` would make them inherit the directory owner, but they don't and I see no other effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing useful, generally.

According to **Sven Mascheck's page on [special permission bits](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/permissions/)**, the `u+s` bit only has an effect on three non-Linux operating systems:

- on HP-UX up to 9, marks the file as [context-dependent](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/hp/9000_hpux/9.x/B2355-90033_HP-UX_9.0_Reference_Vol_3_Sections_1m_4_5_7_Aug92.pdf) *(pages 607, 828)*
- on FreeBSD, if built with the kernel option, allows user ownership to be inherited like `g+s`;
- on SCO OpenServer, enables file versioning.

Comment: But it seems to work on Ubuntu now.

Comment: homebrew uses `u+s` on Mac.

Comment: macOS is probably interpreting it like FreeBSD would.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly has an effect in CentOS8. My nagios core install stopped pinging in the middle of an upgrade with a

'Could not interpret output from ping command'

error on all hosts. Found a resolution and used:

$ chmod u+s /bin/ping

and the issue cleared immediately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).